# The notion of "infinitely differentiable"

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Wiki takes me to the section "smoothness" which I don't entirely get, it's just too much stuff for me.

My question is, what exactly is it?

> An infinitely differentiable function is one that is infinitely differentiable.

Literally, that's what my lecture note says. So I thought the notion is very obvious, so what I had in mind was

> Not infinitely differentiable $\to$ those that reaches a "dead end"
>
> $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n$ since $n+1$ differetiations will make it $0$ and I thought this can be considered a "dead end" for instance.

Then,

> Infinitely differentiable $\to$ doesn't have a dead end
>
> $f(x)=\sin{x}$ or $f(x)=e^{nx}$ say. These can be differentiated as many times as one wishes, but it doesn't have a dead end. It keeps changing to another function, coming back, or staying like itself.

However, it seems like my understanding has been wrong. In a probelem's solution in class, I have been told,

> $f(x)=xy$ is a polynomial so it is infinitely differentiable.

In my way of thinking, polynomials meet a dead end so they are not. But my class has claimed otherwise. So what exactly are functions that are infinitely differentiable, and what are not? Sure, $0$ differentiated then it is $0$ so we *can* differentiate it a million or gazzilion times in a sense.

But what functions aren't? Functions that cannot be defined at a certain point then?

Comment: Once you differentiate a polynomial enough times you get $0$. This is not a dead end, because it is a differentiable function, whose derivative is again $0$. A dead end should be something non-differentiable.

Comment: Is there an explicit and simple example of something non-differentiable? Is it something like $\frac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$?

Comment: Consider $f(x) = |x|$. Is it differentiable (at least once) everywhere on $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Alex The absolute value function is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: The function $f(x)=x|x|$ is differentiable everywhere but its second derivative does not exist at $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, my point was to illustrate what possibilities could arise... @JohnDouma

Comment: Think i got a better idea now guys, thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in most situations, infinitely differentiable means that you are allowed to differentiate the function as many times as you wish, since these derivatives exist (everywhere). The value of the derivatives is irrelevant, of course.

A function is *not* infinitely differentiable if there exist an integer $n \geq 1$ and a point $x_0$ such that the derivative of order $n$ at $x_0$ does not exist.

Comment: What about $1\over x$ at $x_0=0$?

Comment: Thanks guys, I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991475/why-is-the-absolute-value-function-not-differentiable-at-x-0/991559 which explains it visually for the case. But yes, what about $\frac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$? Do we deem it to "not have a limit" there since it approaches infinity?

Comment: Indeed. Although we can infinitely differentiate the function, there *is* a discontinuity at $x=0$ in differentials of all orders.  It is not smooth. @Melba1993

Comment: @SimpleArt the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ is smooth in its domain, namely $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. A necessary condition to defined the derivative is that the function must be *defined* at the point. And, we all know, continuous.

Answer (score 9):

To add to @Crostul's comment, if at some step you get $$f^{(n)}(x) = |x|$$ then you have reached a *dead end* and this is indeed not differentiable further (because the derivative at $x=0$ does not exist, although the function is continuous there).

Any polynomial or simple exponent is infinitely differentiable (exponents cover sines and cosines as well)...

**UPDATE**

For an example of a function that would reach such a dead end, consider
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3, & x \ge 0 \\ -x^3, & x < 0 \end{cases}
$$
and note that
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases} 3x^2, & x \ge 0 \\ -3x^2, & x < 0 \end{cases}
$$
and
$$
f''(x) = \begin{cases} 6x, & x \ge 0 \\ -6x, & x < 0 \end{cases}
 = 6|x|
$$
and you have reached a dead end.

Comment: Can you give an example of a function that reaches such a dead-end?

Comment: @niloderoock please see the update