# Making an absolute value function differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives, absolute-value

> If I define a function as follows:
>
> $$ f(x) = |x| , \: \text{if x $\neq$ 0}, \: \\ \text{and} \\ f(x) = 0
>  , \: \text{if $x = 0$}. \\ $$
>
> Is $f$ differentiable?

I think it is. The absolute value function is differentiable everywhere except from $x=0$. The way $f$ is defined above, however, its derivative at $x=0$ is $f' = 0$ and thereby $f$ is differentiable.

Am I mistaken?

Comment: *its derivative at $x=0$ is $f'=0$* Are you sure?

Comment: You don't need the second line of the definition: $f(x)=|x|$ is enough, because $|0|=0$. Think about that for a bit, and perhaps you will see where you have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some answers already, but let me just point out what might be a source of confusion: *if a function is defined piecewise, it can be differentiated piecewise, except at the endpoints which must be checked individually.*

For instance, your function is
$$
    f(x) = |x| = \begin{cases} x & x > 0 \\ -x & x < 0 \\ 0 & x = 0\end{cases}
$$
It's tempting to say, “Well, $x$, $-x$, and $0$ are all differentiable functions, so
$$
\color{red}{
    f'(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0 \\ -1 & x < 0 \\ 0 & x = 0\end{cases}
}
$$
and therefore $f$ is differentiable for all $x$.”

But actually, we can only differentiate on the interior of the pieces.  That is,
$$
    f'(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0 \\ -1 & x < 0 \end{cases}
$$
is true.  But to check whether $f$ is differentiable at $0$, we need to decide if
$$
    \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|h|}{h}
$$
exists.  In fact, this limit does not exist.

The moral of the story is that differentiability requires checking not just a point, but a neighborhood around that point.  This is why when it can fail to be differentiable at the transition points of piecewise-defined functions.

Answer (score 1):

What you have defined *is* the absolute value function, since $\lvert 0 \rvert = 0$. But the absolute value is not differentiable at $x = 0$, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991475/why-is-the-absolute-value-function-not-differentiable-at-x-0).

Answer (score 0):

For $t \ne 0$ we have $\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}= \frac{|t|}{t}.$

Hence $\lim_{t \to 0+0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=1$ and $\lim_{t \to 0-0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=-1$.

Consequence: $f$ is not differentiable at $0.$